# FCM push notifications on mutliple TWA on same domain

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity, twa

I am working on a use case where I am trying to create multiple TWAs which run on same domain but with different routes. Like this

- TWA-1: [www.example.com/pwa1](http://www.example.com/pwa1)
- TWA-2: [www.example.com/pwa2](http://www.example.com/pwa2)
- TWA-3: [www.example.com/pwa3](http://www.example.com/pwa3)

I have gone through this [thread](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/svgomg-twa/issues/70)  to know that creating multiple TWAs on same domain is doable.
But I am not able to understand how push notifications will work in this case.

Since firebase credentials are same on the three TWA , so I assume that same FCM token will be generated for all three TWA(since they run on browser) . Now If I send a push notifications to TWA-1 , how do I manage to open the targeted TWA on notification click and not the other.

Please excuse brevity.